# Custom UITableViewCell width for all orientations

Tags: iphone, uitableview

When you create a custom UITableViewCell, how do you know what the width should be if the app for the iPad can support all orientations.  I'd like to lay my information out in IB but I don't know if I make the cell's width the width of when it's in Portrait or Landscape.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to know this. Use the Size inspector to lay the subviews out with resizing "springs and struts" so that they work regardless of the cell's width (or, for that matter, height).

Comment: Also known as a view's `autoresizingMask`. The UI doesn't contain any mentions of "springs" or "struts" and may be confusing to novice users.

Comment: The UI doesn't contain any mentions of "autoresizingMask" either. That's why I didn't use that term. He said he wanted to work in the nib, I tried to describe what the nib editor shows. Moreover, unless you understand that those things *are* springs and struts, the UI *is* confusing.

Comment: But it does say "Autosizing", which is way closer than springs and struts. :)

Comment: @matt If you add an object in code to the TableViewCell, how do you set it to a certain distance from the RHS?  Do you determine which orientation you are in, then put it's origin.x a certain distance from the end?   Thx.

Comment: I still don't see why you care "which orientation you are in". You know the cell's contentView bounds at that moment, so place the subview of its contentView where you want it, just as you would if this weren't a table view cell and if there were no such thing as rotation.